# How to update multiple images in kartik Upload widget?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

Here i can only able preview the images on update the model. I want to load the images properly so user can remove one r more file and update will work accordingly  Here is my controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $session_data = \common\models\Customer::find()->where(['user_id' => $model->customer_user_id])->one();
    $towing = \common\models\TowingRequest::find()->where(['id' => $model->towing_request_id])->one();
    $images_old = \common\models\Images::find()->where(['=', 'vehicle_id', $model->id])->all();
    $images = \common\models\Images::find()->where(['=', 'vehicle_id', $model->id])->one();

    if (!$images) {
        $images = new \common\models\Images();
    }
    if ($images_old) {
        foreach ($images_old as $image) {
            $baseurl = \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl;
            $image_url = $baseurl . '../backend/uploads/' . $image->thumbnail;
            $all_images[] = Html::img("$image_url", ['class' => 'file-preview-image']);
        }
    } else {
        $all_images = '';
    }
    $vehiclefeatures = new \common\models\VehicleFeatures();
    $vehiclecondition = new \common\models\VehicleCondition();
    $featuredata = \common\models\VehicleFeatures::find()->where(['=', 'vehicle_id', $model->id])->all();

    $conditiondata = \common\models\VehicleCondition::find()->where(['=', 'vehicle_id', $model->id])->all();
    $features = \common\models\Features::find()->all();
    //  $vf = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM features f left join vehicle_features vf on vf.features_id=f.id;')->queryAll();
    $condition = \common\models\Condition::find()->all();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $towing->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $vehiclefeatures->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $vehiclecondition->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $images->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $towing->save();

        if (!$model->save()) {

            $result = [];
            // The code below comes from ActiveForm::validate(). We do not need to validate the model
            // again, as it was already validated by save(). Just collect the messages.
            foreach ($model->getErrors() as $attribute => $errors) {
                $result[Html::getInputId($model, $attribute)] = $errors;
            }
            return $this->asJson(['validation' => $result]);
            // Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 422;
        }
        //delet vehicle features and add new features
        $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->delete('vehicle_features', 'vehicle_id = ' . $model->id)
            ->execute();
        if ($vehiclefeatures->value) {
            $vehicle_feature = \common\models\VehicleFeatures::inert_vehicle_feature($model, $vehiclefeatures->value);
        }
        //delete vehicle condition and add new features
        $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->delete('vehicle_condition', 'vehicle_id = ' . $model->id)
            ->execute();
        if ($vehiclecondition->value) {

            $vehicle_condition = \common\models\VehicleCondition::inert_vehicle_condition($model, $vehiclecondition->value);
        }
        $photo = UploadedFile::getInstances($images, 'name');

        if ($photo) {

            $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                ->delete('images', 'vehicle_id = ' . $model->id)
                ->execute();

            $save_images = \common\models\Images::save_container_images($model->id, $photo);

        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'towing' => $towing,
        'images' => $images,
        'features' => $features,
        'condition' => $condition,
        'vehiclefeatures' => $vehiclefeatures,
        'vehiclecondition' => $vehiclecondition,
        'all_images' => $all_images,
        'featuredata' => $featuredata,
        'conditiondata' => $conditiondata,
        'session_data' => $session_data,
    ]);

}
```

And here is my form where I have an issue on update the images. I know here I am just previewing the image by adding it in `$all_images[]` in the controller and  `initialPreview => $all_images` in form to just show it on upload. Now I want exactly is to load the images properly so I can remove any image and can able to add more images. I just want here is how to load all the images properly in the upload widget on update After uploading it properly on update i can process it on the controller that i will delete and unlink all images and uploading the updating files

**Here is my form with model images**

```
 <?=
        $form->field($images, 'name[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
            'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*', 'multiple' => true],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'previewFileType' => 'image',
                'allowedFileExtensions' => ['jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp','jpeg'],
                'showUpload' => true,
                'initialPreview' => $all_images,
                'overwriteInitial' => true,

            ],
        ]);
        ?>
```

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam have a look bro i think it will take a minute for you

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam have u see this bro...?

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam  Bro stuck here badly waiting for your help

Comment: Did you try enabling ajax upload, I have this working, if you still need this I will share some of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii2 Fileinput Upload Multiple Images, AJAX based Images Previews and Delete Images.

Please Refer For Multiple Images : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53832224/2218492

```
Table : products_images
id (Primary)
product_id  (FK)
image

Table : product
id (Primary)
Name
ect
```

Here View Forms...

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use kartik\widgets\FileInput;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?php echo '<label class="control-label">Choose an Image file(.png, .jpg)</label>'; ?>

<?php
//For Update Form : Fetch Uploaded Images and create Array to preview
$imagesList = array();
$imagesListId = array();
foreach ($model->productsImages as $img) {
    $imagesList[] = Url::base(TRUE) . '/' . $img->image;
    $imagesListId[]['key'] = $img->id;
}
?>

<?php
    $empty_image = Url::base(TRUE) . "/uploads/image-upload-empty.png";

    echo FileInput::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'products_image[]',
        'name' => 'products_image[]',
        'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*', 'id' => 'products_image_id'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'initialPreview' => $imagesList,
            'initialPreviewConfig' => $imagesListId,
            'deleteUrl' => Url::to(['products/delete-image']),
            'showCaption' => false,
            'showRemove' => false,
            'showUpload' => false,
            'browseClass' => 'btn btn-primary col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6',
            'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> ',
            'browseLabel' => 'Upload Image',
            'allowedFileExtensions' => ['jpg', 'png'],
            'previewFileType' => ['jpg', 'png'],
            'initialPreviewAsData' => true,
            'overwriteInitial' => false,
            "uploadUrl" => Url::to(['products/upload']),
            'uploadExtraData' => ['products_id' => $model->id, 'is_post' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'new' : 'update'],
            'msgUploadBegin' => Yii::t('app', 'Please wait, system is uploading the files'),
            //'msgUploadThreshold' => Yii::t('app', 'Please wait, system is uploading the files'),
            //'msgUploadEnd' => Yii::t('app', 'Done'),
            'msgFilesTooMany' => 'Maximum 15 products Images are allowed to be uploaded.',
            'dropZoneClickTitle' => '',
            "uploadAsync" => true,
            "browseOnZoneClick" => true,
            "dropZoneTitle" => '<img src=' . $empty_image . ' />',
            'fileActionSettings' => [
                'showZoom' => true,
                'showRemove' => true,
                'showUpload' => false,
            ],
            'validateInitialCount' => true,
            'maxFileCount' => 15,
            'maxFileSize' => 5120, //5mb
            'msgPlaceholder' => 'Select attachments',
        ],
        'pluginEvents' => [
            'filebatchselected' => 'function(event, files) {
              $(this).fileinput("upload");

              }',
            /* 'uploadExtraData' => 'function() {
              var out = {}, key, i = 0;
              $(".kv-input:visible").each(function() {
              $el = $(this);
              key = $el.hasClass("kv-new") ? "new_" + i : "init_" + i;
              out[key] = $el.val();
              i++;
              });

              return out;
              }', */
            'filepredelete' => 'function(event, files) {
                //var abort = true;
                var index = uploaded_images.indexOf(files);
                if (index !== -1) uploaded_images.splice(index, 1);
                 console.log(uploaded_images);
                 $("#productsmaster-images_array").val(uploaded_images);
               //return abort;   
            }',
            'fileuploaded' => 'function(event, data, previewId, index){
               //alert( data.response.initialPreviewConfig[0].key);
          uploaded_images.push(data.response.initialPreviewConfig[0].key);
            console.log(uploaded_images);
            $("#productsmaster-images_array").val(uploaded_images);
          }',
        /* 'filepreupload' => 'function(event, data, previewId, index){
          var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra,
          response = data.response, reader = data.reader;
          console.log(data.jqXHR);
          console.log("File pre upload triggered");
          }', */
        ],
    ]);
    ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'images_array')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>

<?php echo '<br>' ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></i> UPLOAD FILE', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary'], ['students/create']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<?php
$script = <<< JS
   // initialize array    
   var uploaded_images = [];  
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Here Controller file:

```
<?php

/*
     * Post products Images Upload Action Via FileInput Yii2 Extention.
     */

    public function actionUpload() {
        $files = array();
        $allwoedFiles = ['jpg', 'png'];
        if ($_POST['is_post'] == 'update') {
            $products_id = $_POST['products_id'];
            if ($_FILES) {
                $tmpname = $_FILES['ProductsMaster']['tmp_name']['products_image'][0];
                $fname = $_FILES['ProductsMaster']['name']['products_image'][0];
                //Get the temp file path
                $tmpFilePath = $tmpname;
                //Make sure we have a filepath
                if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
                    //save the filename
                    $shortname = $fname;
                    $size = $_FILES['ProductsMaster']['size']['products_image'][0];
                    $ext = substr(strrchr($shortname, '.'), 1);
                    if (in_array($ext, $allwoedFiles)) {
                        //save the url and the file
                        $newFileName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(40) . "." . $ext;
                        //Upload the file into the temp dir
                        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, 'uploads/products/' . $newFileName)) {
                            $productsImages = new productsImages();
                            $productsImages->products_id = $products_id;
                            $productsImages->image_for = 'products';
                            $productsImages->image = 'uploads/products/' . $newFileName;
                            $productsImages->created_at = time();
                            $productsImages->save();
                            $files['initialPreview'] = Url::base(TRUE) . '/uploads/products/' . $newFileName;
                            $files['initialPreviewAsData'] = true;
                            $files['initialPreviewConfig'][]['key'] = $productsImages->id;
                            return json_encode($files);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } /* else {
              return json_encode(['error' => 'No files found for pload.']);
              } */
            return json_encode($files);
        } else {
            if (isset($_POST)) {
                if ($_FILES) {
                    $files = ProductsMaster::SaveTempAttachments($_FILES);
                    return json_encode($files);
                    $result = ['files' => $files];
                    Yii::$app->response->format = trim(Response::FORMAT_JSON);
                    return $result;
                } /* else {
                  echo json_encode(['error' => 'No files found for pload.']);
                  } */
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Uploaded Images Delete Action on Update Forms Action
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function actionDeleteImage() {
        $key = $_POST['key'];
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            $products_image = ProductsImages::find()->where(['id' => $key])->one();
            unlink(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/' . $products_image->image);
            $products_image->delete();
            return true;
        } else {
            unlink(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/uploads/products/temp/' . $key);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
    ** Create Products
    **/
     public function actionCreate() {

          //Products Images
        // temp store image moved and save to database.. with generated forms.. 
            if (count($model->images_array) > 0) {
                $images_array = explode(',', $model->images_array);
                if (!empty($images_array) && $model->images_array != '') {
                    foreach ($images_array as $image) {
                        $file = Yii::$app->basePath . '/uploads/products/temp/' . $image;
                        $rename_file = Yii::$app->basePath . '/uploads/products/' . $image;
                        rename($file, $rename_file);
                        $productsImages = new productsImages();
                        $productsImages->products_id = $model->id;
                        $productsImages->image_for = 'products';
                        $productsImages->image = 'uploads/products/' . $image;
                        $productsImages->created_at = time();
                        $productsImages->save();
                    }
                }
            }

     }


    ?>
```

Here Model
I added a load function to the attachment model.

```
<?php 

/*
     * Save Temp Images 
     */

    public static function SaveTempAttachments($attachments) {
        $files = "";
        $allwoedFiles = ['jpg', 'png'];
        if ($_FILES) {
            $tmpname = $_FILES['ProductsMaster']['tmp_name']['products_image'];
            $fname = $_FILES['ProductsMaster']['name']['products_image'];

            if (!empty($attachments)) {
                if (count($fname) > 0) {
                    //Loop through each file
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fname); $i++) {
                        //Get the temp file path
                        $tmpFilePath = $tmpname[$i];
                        //Make sure we have a filepath
                        if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
                            //save the filename
                            $shortname = $fname[$i];
                            $size = $attachments['ProductsMaster']['size']['products_image'][$i];
                            $ext = substr(strrchr($shortname, '.'), 1);
                            if (in_array($ext, $allwoedFiles)) {
                                //save the url and the file
                                $newFileName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(40) . "." . $ext;
                                //Upload the file into the temp dir
                                if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, 'uploads/products/temp/' . $newFileName)) {
                                    $files['initialPreview'] = Url::base(TRUE) . '/uploads/products/temp/' . $newFileName;
                                    $files['initialPreviewAsData'] = true;
                                    // $files['uploadExtraData'][]['is_post'] = 'new';
                                    $files['initialPreviewConfig'][]['key'] = $newFileName;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $files;
    }

?>
```